# Prove that if $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x) = L \neq 0$ and $\lim_{x\to 0} g(x)$ does not exist, then $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)g(x)$ does not exist.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, solution-verification, epsilon-delta

I have a proof to this that seems correct and rigorous, but I have been in an echo chamber with no feedback from a teacher/answer key on my math lately, so I'm looking for confirmation.

Proof:

Suppose $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)g(x)$ exists and is equal to M.

For any $\epsilon$, define $\epsilon_1 = \frac{|L|\epsilon}{2(1+\left|\frac{M}{L}\right|)}$.
This means that for all $\epsilon > 0$, $\epsilon_1 > 0$.

Then for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta_1 > 0$ such that for all $x$,

if $0 < |x| < \delta_1$, then $|f(x)g(x)-M| < \epsilon_1$.

Since the limit of $f$ is given, for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta_2 > 0$ such that for all $x$,

if $0 < |x| < \delta_2$, then $|f(x)-L| < \epsilon_1$

By taking $\epsilon = 1+|\frac{M}{L}|$, there exists $\delta_{21} > 0$ such that for all $x$,

if $0 < |x| < \delta_{21}$, then $|f(x)-L| < \frac{|L|}{2}$

Define $\delta = \min(\delta_1,\delta_2,\delta_{21})$

For any $\epsilon > 0$, and for all $x$,

if $0 < |x| < \delta$, then $|f(x)-L| < \epsilon_1$, and $|f(x)-L| < \frac{|L|}{2}$, and $|f(x)g(x)-M| < \epsilon_1$.

Manipulating the last inequality,
$$\left|f(x)\left(g(x)-\frac{M}{L}\right)+\frac{M}{L}(f(x)-L)\right| < \epsilon_1$$
$$\left|f\left(x\right)\right|\left|g\left(x\right)-\frac{M}{L}\right|-\left|\frac{M}{L}\right|\left|f\left(x\right)-L\right| < \epsilon_1$$
Based on $|f(x)-L| < \frac{|L|}{2}$, it is true that $|f(x)| > \frac{|L|}{2}$. Using this and $|f(x)-L| < \epsilon_1$,
$$\frac{\left|L\right|}{2}\left|g\left(x\right)-\frac{M}{L}\right|-\left|\frac{M}{L}\right|\epsilon_1 < \epsilon_1$$
$$\left|g\left(x\right)-\frac{M}{L}\right|<\frac{2\left(1+\left|\frac{M}{L}\right|\right)\epsilon_1}{\left|L\right|} = \epsilon$$

Therefore, $\lim_{x\to 0} g(x) = \frac{M}{L}$.

Contradiction.

$\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)g(x)$ does not exist.

Please also give any critique on my formatting/wording since I have minimal experience with it.

Comment: If $\lim f(x)g(x)=M,$ then $g(x)=\frac{f(x)g(x)}{f(x)}\to \frac{M}{L}.$

Comment: That said, your proof is correct.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Oops, you're right. Thanks for the feedback!